# Threading with exception... Why it keeps ignoring the pass keyword?

Tags: python, exception

I am stuck with a Python issue related to threading.

```
import threading
import time
import random
import sys
import echo

class presence(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, cb):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.callback = cb

    def run(self):
        minValue = 0
        maxValue = 3

        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                if random.randint(minValue, maxValue) == 1:
                    self.callback(1)
                elif random.randint(minValue, maxValue) == 2:
                    raise Exception('An error')
                else:
                    self.callback(0)
        except:
            print 'Exception caught!'
            pass

def showAlert():
    echo.echo('Someone is behind the door!')

def count(x):
        if x == 1:
            showAlert()
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

That is how I call it:

```
t2 = presence.presence(presence.count)
t2.start()
```

I eventually get an `"Exception caught!"`, but the thread stops not returning alerts anymore.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: For future reference: "Ignoring the pass keyword" is [a specified behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement).  The `pass` statement doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try/except` block should be inside the loop.  For example:

```
while True:
    ...
    elif random.randint(minValue, maxValue) == 2:
        try:
            raise Exception('An error')
        except Exception:
            print 'Exception caught!'
```

Otherwise, the loop will be exited when the exception is raised and Python jumps to the `except:` block in order to handle it.

You'll notice too that I selectively placed the `try/except` block in my example to only cover the code that might actually raise the exception.  This is a best practice and I recommend it for your code.  Having a `try/except` block enclose large portions of code decreases readability and also wastes space (lots of lines are unnecessarily indented).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but isn't this try just "trying" to raise an exception, which will actually always work? I am actually trying to simulate an error ( this code will be later replaced by sensors for my Raspberry Pi ;-) meaning I might not get a random number at all, but an error...

Comment: The code I posted is an example.  I expect you to replace `raise Exception('An error')` with whatever code might raise the exception you are handling.  My point was that you need to stop Python from jumping out of the loop in order to handle the exception.